# OAuth2 - my access token is a server-side secret, yes, so how do I use it with AJAX?

Tags: php, ajax, oauth-2.0

I'm using Brent Shaffer's OAuth2 for PHP (https://github.com/bshaffer/oauth2-server-php)

I call my internal APIs like this:

```
$data = $fc->callAPI($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']  . '/api/v1/test-member-search.php',
    $fc->internalAccessTokenForAPI(), null);
```

`callAPI` takes url, token, data and as you can see, I have a method for getting my own token. `callAPI` is really just a cURL wrapper:

```
public function callAPI($fullURL, $token, $data ) {
    $headers = [
        'Accept: */*',
        'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Authorization: Bearer ' . $token
    ];

    if (!$data) { $data = ["data" => "none"]; }

    // open connection
    $ch = curl_init();

    // set curl options
    $options = [
        CURLOPT_URL => $fullURL,
        CURLOPT_POST => count($data),
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($data),
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    ];
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);

    // execute
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}
```

The OAuth2 server can take the Authorization header or if not good, it checks for `access_token` in the POST.

So that's how I access the API with PHP but what about an AJAX call like below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var request;
        $("#searchform").submit(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var $form = $(this);
            var serializedData = $form.serialize();
            request = $.ajax({
                url: "/api/v1/test-member-search.php",
                type: "post",
                data: serializedData
            });
            ...
            ... other stuff
```

This is where my knowledge ends. I can "make it work" by simply using PHP to echo the token from the PHP session as a hidden input called `access_token`, or I could include it in the AJAX request data, but this makes the access token (which has a 1 hour life) visible to the browser client.

Knowing the access token gives the ability to make API calls so how do I call the API via AJAX and keep the token hidden?

Comment: If you don't want to send the token to the browser you have to proxy the API request, i.e. don't request the API directly but some PHP script that forwards the request after adding the Authorization header.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want your client (user agent = browser) to make direct calls to an API, which is perfectly fine. In that case, the token is indeed "visible" in the browser tab which runs your JS.

In that case you need to add the header "Authorization: Bearer " to your ajax request.

For instance:

```
request = $.ajax({
  url: "/api/v1/test-member-search.php",
  type: "post",
  headers: {
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`
  },
  data: serializedData
});
```

This must be done exclusively on TLS (https) otherwise your token may be seen by an attacker.

Comment: Thanks, but my question is about avoiding this.

Comment: Then Peter's answer is what you are looking for.